# redirecting to the controller's action from exception handler once it caught by the exception?

Tags: java, spring, response.redirect

i have used following code to redirect to controller's action from the exception handler, it is working but flowid is getting appended to the browser's URL in the client side. is there any alternative way to do this without having that flowid? you can see the URL as well below
http://localhost:8080/sample/home?flowId=fd19e86a-d9f8-485c-858c-41bcc5a10cd9

```
@ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, DataAccessExceptionex) {
        logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/home");
        mav.addObject("exception", ex);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
       return mav;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect():

```
    @ExceptionHandler(DataAccessException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse response, DataAccessException ex) {
        logger.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);

        response.sendRedirect("/sample");

        return null;
      }
```

Comment: how to set attributes make available to the redirecting url method before redirect??

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of `spring redirect`. You can change the same following the below steps:

- **---XML Based Configurations---***:

  For `XML` based configurations, just add `<mvc:annotation-driven ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect="true" />` in your `custom servlet xml configuration`.
- **---Java Based Configuration---**:

  You can autowired the existing `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and set the default `IgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect` property as `true` pointed out in as follows-

  ```
   @EnableWebMvc
   @Configuration
   public class CustomWebConfig {
       @Autowired
       private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

       @PostConstruct
       public void init() {
          requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
       }
   }
  ```

Now you can use the same `ModelAndView` as you used in your example for the `redirect`.